# Drawing outside a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a UIView where I would like to draw a Circle that extends past the frame of the UIView,
I have set the masksToBounds to NO - expecting that I can draw past outside the bounds of the UIView by 5 pixels on the right and bottom.

I expect the oval to not get clipped but it does get clipped and does not draw outside the bounds?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    int width = self.bounds.size.width;
    int height = self.bounds.size.height;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    //// Rounded Rectangle Drawing
    //// Oval Drawing
    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, width+5, height+5)];
    [[UIColor magentaColor] setFill];
    [ovalPath fill];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    ovalPath.lineWidth = 1;
    [ovalPath stroke];

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/DrawingModel.html

> UIView and NSView automatically configure the drawing environment of a
>   view before its drawRect: method is invoked. (In the AppKit framework,
>   configuring the drawing environment is called locking focus.) As part
>   of this configuration, the view class creates a graphics context for
>   the current drawing environment.
>
> This graphics context is a Quartz object (CGContext) that contains
>   information the drawing system requires, such as the colors to apply,
>   the drawing mode (stroke or fill), line width and style information,
>   font information, and compositing options. (In the AppKit, an object
>   of the NSGraphicsContext class wraps a CGContext object.) A graphics
>   context object is associated with a window, bitmap, PDF file, or other
>   output device and maintains information about the current state of the
>   drawing environment for that entity. A view draws using a graphics
>   context associated with the view’s window. **For a view, the graphics
>   context sets the default clipping region to coincide with the view’s
>   bounds and puts the default drawing origin at the origin of a view’s
>   boundaries.**

Once the clipping region is set, you can only make it smaller. So, what you're trying to do isn't possible in a UIView drawRect:.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this will fix your problem, but it's something to look into.  You're setting `self.layer.masksToBounds = NO` every single time you enter `drawRect`.  You should try setting it inside the init method just once instead, A) because it's unnecessary to do it multiple times and B) because maybe there's a problem with setting it after `drawRect` has already been called--who knows.

Comment: self.layer.masksToBounds = NO will not help clipping